# Reading data occasionally from a socket without closing it

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream

**Info**

I'm trying to find a way to read blocks of data from an incoming socket stream at a set interval, but ignoring the rest of the data and not closing the connection between reads.  I was wondering if anyone had some advice?

The reason I ask is I have been given a network connected analogue to digital converter (ADC) and I want to write a simple oscilloscope application.

Basically once I connect to the ADC and send a few initialisation commands it then takes a few minutes to stabilise, at which point it starts throwing out measurements in a byte stream.

I want to read 1MB of data every few seconds and discard the rest, if I don't discard the rest the ADC will buffer 512kB of readings then pause so any subsequent reads will be of old data.  If I close the connection between reads the ADC then takes a while before it sends data again.

**Problem**

I wrote a simple Python script as a test, in this I used a continuously running thread which would read bytes to an unused buffer, if a flag was set, which seems to work fine.

When I tried this on Android I ran into problems as it seems that only some of the data is being discarded, the ADC still pauses if the update interval is too long.

Where have I made the mistake(s)? My first guess is synchronisation as I'm not sure its working as intended (see the ThreadBucket class).  I'll have to admit spending many hours on playing with this, trying different sync permutations, buffer sizes, `BufferedInputStream` and NIO, but with no luck.

Any input on this would be appreciated, I'm not sure if using a thread like this is the right way to go in Java.

**Code**

The `Reader` class sets up the thread, connects to the ADC, reads data on request and in between activates the bit bucket thread (I've omitted the initialisation and closing for clarity).

```
class Reader {

    private static final int READ_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

    private String mServer;
    private int mPort;
    private Socket mSocket;
    private InputStream mIn;
    private ThreadBucket mThreadBucket;
    private byte[] mData = new byte[1];
    private final byte[] mBuffer = new byte[READ_SIZE];

    Reader(String server, int port) {
        mServer = server;
        mPort = port;
    }

    void setup() throws IOException {

        mSocket = new Socket(mServer, mPort);
        mIn = mSocket.getInputStream();
        mThreadBucket = new ThreadBucket(mIn);
        mThreadBucket.start();

        // Omitted: Send a few init commands a look at the response

        // Start discarding data
        mThreadBucket.bucket(true);
    }

    private int readRaw(int samples) throws IOException {

        int current = 0;

        // Probably fixed size but may change
        if (mData.length != samples)
            mData = new byte[samples];

        // Stop discarding data
        mThreadBucket.bucket(false);
        // Read in number of samples to mData
        while (current < samples) {
            int len = mIn.read(mBuffer);
            if (current > samples)
                current = samples;
            if (current + len > samples)
                len = samples - current;
            System.arraycopy(mBuffer, 0, mData, current, len);
            current += mBuffer.length;
        }
        // Discard data again until the next read
        mThreadBucket.bucket(true);

        return current;
    }
}
```

The `ThreadBucket` class runs continuously, on slurping data to the bit bucket if `mBucket` is true.

The synchronisation is meant to stop either thread from reading data whilst the other one is.

```
public class ThreadBucket extends Thread {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    private final InputStream mIn;
    private Boolean mBucket = false;
    private boolean mCancel = false;

    public ThreadBucket(final InputStream in) throws IOException {

        mIn = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!mCancel && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mBucket)
                    try {
                        mIn.skip(BUFFER_SIZE);
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public synchronized void bucket(final boolean on) {

        mBucket = on;
    }

    public void cancel() {

        mCancel = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read continuously, period, as fast as you can code it, and then manage what you do with the data separately. Don't mix the two up.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion and got an appreciable performance increase.  Unfortunately this wasn't enough so I tried just putting a recv() in a while loop using JNI.  It turns out even this isn't fast enough - back to the drawing board.